# linux server hangs after "running local boot scripts"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, hangs

after a sudden electricity break down one of the company servers (ubuntu) hangs at boot.
I have an OK message for "running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)" but it freeze there and a black screep appears after a couple of minutes.

This is an image from server boot:
http://i40.tinypic.com/30kat5i.jpg

What is the problem and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check what is inside of the script /etc/rc.local?

Comment: Second @dsmsk80. If there are things in there that sleep, background them (`/usr/local/bin/examplecommand.sh &`).

Answer (score 0):

Try Pressing `'CRTL'+'ALT'+'F2'` to see if you can logging to a Console.
That way you might be able to have a look at what the local scripts are doing...   perhaps they are not terminating for what ever reason.

Someone can correct me if I am wrong but I believe that unless these scripts terminate this will hold your boot sequence up like this.

Look for a script that is lunching an secondary binary or service that stays resident.   if found try appending an `'&'` to the end of the execution statement.  This will tell the script to continue with remaining script and not wait for an exit on the child process.

there's a lot of maybes there but...   its a starting point for you.

Were you having issues with Apache before the crash?   not being able to assign a socket to Apache is not a good sign.  Something else for you to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting in safe mode:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-in-safe-mode

> To start Ubuntu into safe mode (Recovery Mode) hold down the left
>   Shift key as the computer starts to boot. If holding the Shift key
>   doesn't display the menu press the Esc key repeatedly to display the
>   GRUB 2 menu. From there you can choose the recovery option.